# How can i input string value and output a value of variable int/float/double

Tags: c++

I try to make code that calculate the average

```
string uD;
int SAMI=24;
cin>>uD;
cout<<uD;
```

if i input string like "SAMI"
the output will be "SAMI"

How can I output the integer of variable value SAMI like this:
input:

```
SAMI
```

output:

```
24
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a mapping between names and numbers you need to implement it yourself. Names of variables do not exist once you compiled the code (only in debug builds for use of a debugger but not as strings accessible in the program).

```
if (uD == "SAMI") std::cout << SAMI;
```

If you have more "named numbers" consider to use a `std::unordered_map` (I used `double` values here, because you ask for int/float/double but in the example there is only an `int`, so I wasn't sure):

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,double> mymap{
       { "SAMI", SAMI },
       { "Foo", 42 }
};
auto it = mymap.find(uD);
if (it == mymap.end()) {
    std::cout << "wrong name";
} else {
    std::cout << it->second;
}
```